# tensorflow object detection stops training automatically without an error message

Tags: object-recognition, 3d-object-recognition

i've used this same code with a dataset that is much smaller and the code worked perfectly. i've now increased the size of the dataset and the model trains around 100 steps and stops. i reduced the size of the dataset by reducing the size of the files from 378mb to around 87mb and also deleted around 100 images.. does anyone know how i can overcome this issue?
[image]

Comment: This looks like an update to your last question. Please edit that with the new information instead of asking a new question.

Comment: please do not post a screenshot of text ... post the text instead ... format same as code